# Margin inheritance from child with fixed position

Tags: html, css

Consider the following very simple code:

```
<div id="parent">
 <div id="child">
    Test it
 </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#parent{
position:relative;
margin-left:200px;
color:#FFF;
}
#child{
position:fixed;
top:30px;  
background-color:red;
}
```

I supposed child div would not inherit margin-left from parent div since child breaks the normal flow. However, not only does it inherit the 200px margin; moreover, if I try to assign  margin-left:50px to child div the result is a left margin of 250px!! Why that happens and in what way may I change it?

Thank you

Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/rCMx2/

Comment: Child breaks normal flow? Can you explain more what do you mean by that? As far as I see, the hierarchy is maintained exactly how it should be.

Comment: It is fixed position, mate...

Comment: If you are saying `position:fixed` will break the hierarchy. I am afraid that is not the case.

Comment: it's not caused by the inherit margin, in fact the margin is not inherited. It's just because of the initial position when the position mode switches from static to absolute position (including fixed, absolute and relative), see the answer of PhistucK, that's the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason - unless you specify horizontal positioning axes (`left: ...` or `right: ...`), the child element, even if it is a fixed positioned one, will still be horizontally positioned like it would have been without being fixed positioned.
Same for vertical axes (`top: ...` or `bottom: ...`) and its vertical position.

It would just not move from that initial position, since it is a fixed positioned element.

So, in other words, declaring `position: fixed` and `top: ...` does not change the horizontal position of the element, only its vertical. Its horizontal position is still its natural one.

The solution - add `left: ...` or `right: ...` to the fixed positioned element in order to 'disconnect' it from its initial horizontal position.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a margin of 50px on top of the margin for your parent.  This might help you visualize what is happening:

```
#parent{
  margin-left:200px;
  color:#FFF;
  border:2px solid #f0f;
  overflow:visible;
}

#child{
  top:30px;  
  background-color:red;
  margin:20px;
  border:2px solid #0f0;
}
```

Try that.  Can you more easily visualize what is happening now?  Note that I removed the "position" attributes.

In order to achieve a more specific result, I need to know WHAT you want your final layout to look like.

Comment: I want div child not to inherit margin from parent

Comment: The div does NOT inherit the margin -- it sits INSIDE the parent, which already is positioned with a margin.  You can always try adding a negative margin to your child element.  Make sure you put "overflow:visible" in the parent, though!

Comment: In case the child is fixed position with top:30px it sits OUTSIDE the parent. However, it still carries a 200px left margin. Why? That's what I cannot understand...

Comment: @ILIAS - I updated my post to answer both of your questions (the reason and the solution). In case you are satisfied, do not forget to mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

He is taking the position of 200px div parent who is on. As the div child is fixed, she is taking on the father as parameter to leave the stream. 
You can remove the div son of his father, separating from them.

And align the div fixed to left: 50px out instead of using margin-left: 50px.

Hope this helps.

Here's an example: http://zip.net/bjmY23